# Blender 2.8 RC2 Outliner restrict icons

Tags: outliner

I'm just downloaded (current available) Blender 2.8 RC2, and little confused: I see NO restriction icons [commands] in Outliner:

1. Restrict Viewport Visibility
2. Restrict Viewport Selection
3. Restrict Rendering

I Have "hide in viewport" only. Is this OK? Or maybe I miss something? How to get back all 3 restrictions?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get all restriction icons by clicking on the filter dropdown.

[image]

Once they are all enabled:

[image]

Comment: I miss it. Thank you!