# turn off rendering in outliner view

Tags: modifiers, outliner

I'm interested in removing one object's geometry from another. I should be able to do this with a boolean modifier on the larger object (the "car") targeting another object (the "window"). I would then like the window not to show when rendering. I expected to find this option in the outliner view (based on [this forum post](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-not-to-render-hidden-objects/514282)), but maybe this has changed in blender 2.80? In the outliner window, I see the "Hide in Viewport" option, but where is the option to hide it in the final render?

[image: the Hide in Viewport option in the outliner window] 
[image: the boolean operation looks good in the 3D window]
[image: the "window" operation that keeps appearing in the rendered output]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146192/blender-2-8-rc2-outliner-restrict-icons

Answer (score 0):

The icons can be hidden and shown with the "filter" dropdown.
@rjg linked to an answer to this effect. This question is a duplicate.